# Keep cursor pos when editing a div which has contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a text editor which is formatted, not based on buttons. I have the following JS:

```
    function titleFocus() {
        $(".title").css("border", "1px solid #666666");
    }
    function titleBlur() {
        $(".title").css("border", "none");
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
            var inputString = $(".input").html();
            var newInputString= inputString.replace(/:strong:(.*?):strong:/g, ':strong:<strong class="written">$1</strong>:strong:');
            var newInputString= newInputString.replace(/:b:(.*?):b:/g, ':b:<strong class="written">$1</strong>:b:');
            var newInputString= newInputString.replace(/:italic:(.*?):italic:/g, ':italic:<strong class="written">$1</strong>:italic:');
            var newInputString= newInputString.replace(/:i:(.*?):i:/g, ':i:<strong class="written">$1</strong>:i:');
            if (newInputString !== inputString) {
                console.log (newInputString);    
                $(".input").html(newInputString);
            }
        });
    });
```

The thing is, after I have done a formatting que (`:strong:` or `italic`) then every time I type a character the cursor goes to the start. It also does this after you initially write a formatting que. How can I prevent this? Also, is there a more efficient way of achieving what I'm doing? I feal that having a chunk of JS run every time someone types a character will cause lag.

**EDIT:** Apparently, this code causes formatted things to duplicate.

E.G:`:strong:<strong class="written"><strong class="written">TEXT</strong></strong>:strong:`

Comment: you don't want to replace the full contents every time, you should just insert the new markup using appendChild/insertBefore/etc. yeah, it's much harder to do, but the UX will be worth it.

Comment: @dan Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.